# Recaptcha 2 how to check if user cancels puzzle

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

How to detect if a user is cancelling the Recaptcha puzzle:
[image]

It is possible to click outside the dialog box and close the dialog. However, there doesn't seem to be any callback to that action. It is necessary to return user to previous action.

We are initializing Recaptcha 2 programmatically like this:

```js
grecaptcha.render('grecaptchaContainer', {
  'sitekey': OUR_SITE_KEY,
  'callback': grecaptcha_responds,
  'expired-callback': grecaptcha_expires,
});
```

The `callback` function is called, no problem.

The `expired-callback` function is never called. I figured this function will be called when the user cancels/waits too long. But this is not the case.

Could not find anything in the docs or on the web. Any takers?

Comment: I face the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: This seems to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571782/is-there-any-recaptcha-v2-close-event)

Comment: This is my solution to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72387948/2800468